# Sonar runner + ReSharper getting message "ReSharper plugin is running in deprecated mode"

Tags: sonarqube, resharper, sonar-runner

Configuration:

```
Sonar: V. 5.1.1.
C#-PlugIn: V. 4.0
ReSharper-PlugIn: V. 2.0
ReSharper-InspectCode: V. 9.1.1
```

I'm getting the message "ReSharper plugin is running in deprecated mode" even though I have configured it as recommended [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/ReSharper+Plugin).

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer* The mode where R# is executed by the SonarQube analyzer is going to be deprecated starting from next week.

*Long [and boring] answer*

The re-use reports mode will replace it, where you invoke `inspectcode.exe` yourself and provide the path to its report to the SonarQube analyzer.

The R# 2.0 plugin has been released to work with the MSBuild SonarQube Runner 1.0 which will be released next week.

The MSBuild SonarQube Runner will replace the Visual Studio Boostrapper plugin.

Now, the re-use reports mode of the R# 2.0 plugin only works with the MSBuild SonarQube Runner, and cannot be used with the Visual Studio Bootstrapper. This explains why we have to wait until the MSBuild SonarQube Runner is released before being able to officially deprecate the current mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that long [and NOT boring] answer! So I'll have to wait for next week.

Comment: @Fischermaen and Dinesh  - Currently I am using msbuild sonarquberunner 2.0 with inspectcode.exe as well opencover.exe for unittest, do I have to worry about it at all? Because I am also getting deprecation message.